# Problema con una consulta SQL al usar una Fecha

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo un problema con una consulta `SQL` en `Oracle`.

Tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual su resultado siempre me trae vacio todos los campos:

```
SELECT 
        M000.FULTACT000     AS FECHAS,
        M000.NBCLI000       AS CLIENTE,
        M000.G300CTA        AS CUENTA,
        C000.NCNL000        AS CANAL,
        A000.NALDF000       AS ALIADO,
        U000.NBUSUF000      AS GERENTE

FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CNLF000  C000 ON C000.CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.ALDF000  A000 ON A000.IDALDF000 = M000.IDALDF000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.USEJE000 U000 ON U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000
WHERE M000.FULTACT000 = SYSDATE;
```

Si ejecuta dicha consulta, sin el `WHERE M000.FULTACT000 = SYSDATE`, me trae datos.

Lo unico que se me ocurre es que sea un problema con la fecha, hice una consulta para saber la fecha del sistema usando:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

La cual retorna `2019/02/27`.

Si realizo la consulta sin utilizar el `SYSDATE`, es decir:

```
SELECT 
        M000.FULTACT000     AS FECHAS,
        M000.NBCLI000       AS CLIENTE,
        M000.G300CTA        AS CUENTA,
        C000.NCNL000        AS CANAL,
        A000.NALDF000       AS ALIADO,
        U000.NBUSUF000      AS GERENTE

FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CNLF000  C000 ON C000.CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.ALDF000  A000 ON A000.IDALDF000 = M000.IDALDF000
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.USEJE000 U000 ON U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000
WHERE M000.FULTACT000 = '2019/02/27';
```

Sigue sin devolverme algun valor. Siempre retorna vacio.

¿Que podria estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Si haces un `SELECT M000.FULTACT000 FROM M000` en qué formato te devuelve la fecha?

Comment: @MrSman 2019/02/27

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con `TRUNC(M000.FULTACT000) = to_date('2019/02/27','YYYY/MM/DD')`

Comment: Puedes de igual forma probar con to_char(M000.FULTACT000,'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2019/02/27' donde especificas el formato de la fecha

Answer (score 1):

SYSDATE contiene no solo la fecha sino tambien la hora en que se obtuvo.  Si comparas esto con fechas en la base de datos, y si estos datos estan fijos a medianoche (tiempo cero),  nunca habrá un concuerdo.

Prueba esto

```
WHERE cast(WOOD.FULTACT000 as date) =
   cast (sysdate as date).
```

Esto extrae la fecha solamente.  Si los datos no son de tipo date,  tienes que hacer otra transformación.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar colocando la fecha '2019-02-27' en lugar de '2019/02/27', entonces sí te debería mostrar los datos.

Comment: Siempre que no tenga la hora tambien ;) (conviene esperar a que quien pregunto aclare eso)